# Select elements from list based on a distribution

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, distribution

I have a list which contains numbers that are very different from each other as:

> [85, 1966, 1135, 1602, 1225, 35460, 829, 12532, 1923, 4091, 113, 7592,
>   2011, 2179, 886, 18451, 3069, 6400, 9228, 1215, 5, 6484, 1947, 786,
>   21121, 28, 9917, 24747, 20798, 36051,16670, 169, 4497, 32262, 33, 25348, 19127, 1354, 26]

Is there a possibility to extract only 10 elements but these elements to be as representative as possible regarding the distribution of the initial values?

I lack of the mathematical background, so this is the reason I don't try anything yet. Because I have no idea from where to start.

Comment: What type of distribution are you wanting?  top-n, bottom-n, random, nth item, etc?

Comment: I am not sure. I want a distribution that will extract the most representative numbers.

Comment: Start with a histogram to see if there are ranges where more outcomes cluster.

Answer (score 1):

There can be much different distribution with randomness in them in the data. That is, 10 numbers can not properly present the entire list of number. However, something you can try to do is to first `sort` the list and uniformly `sample` 10 numbers from the list by the same interval. As you may notice, this approach tells you by chances that if your data is in the uniform distribution or not. If not, you can tell that if there is a left or right skewness to the data. That will provide you with information to some extent.

Other than the naive approaches, I recommend to study their properties through statistics such as mean, mode, median, min, max, quantiles etc. using [`describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) function from package [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is somewhere a start.